# $.getJSON data into array

Tags: javascript, php, getjson

i'm new in PHP and JAVASCRIPT..
i need to do a little script who takes the data from data.php with 
`$.getJSON("data.php", function(json)..` and push it into 2 arrays in the HTML file, to reuse them.

data.php produce this:

```
[[47,48,48,48,50,51,48,46,47,45,48,47],[25,23,22,21,19,21,24,25,27,29,31,28]]
```

at now i do this, but it doesn't run and i don't know how to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            $row1[] = json[0];
            $row2[]= json[1];           

        }); 
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks to all guys ;)

Comment: I think you are confusing yourself with PHP and JS notations. `$array[]` means to [append data to an array in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying), not JavaScript. Whereas `object[property]` is to [access an object's property value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). However, `$row1[]` in your code is an invalid syntax as you have not defined any object `$row1` nor provided any property within `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

Your assignment syntax is wrong. You can't put `[]` at the end of a variable in Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
        var row1 = json[0];
        var row2 = json[1];
        // put code that uses row1 and row2 here
    }); 
});
```